# With a Javascript Promise, how to close over variables local to the parent scope in a `then`?

Tags: javascript, scope, promise, closures

If I have code like this:

```
Blog.add = function(account) {
  const url = 'http://fetchdata.com';
  response = HTTP.post(url);

  response.then(function(response) {
    // There is no access to account or url here.
  });
};
```

When I break in the `then` closure, I see that `this` is bound to the global object which seems strange to me. Shouldn't it be bound to the `add` function?. I've tried arrow functions with the same result. I'm definitely not understanding what's going on here...

Comment: But there *is* access to `account` and `url` in that function. Not via `this`, however, as those are just simple in-scope variables.

Comment: You didn't use var, let, or const when declaring response.  That makes it a global variable right?

Comment: @RobLouie good catch, but also it really important to see how Blog.add() has been called. Besides, we already have explanations here now.

Comment: Right, his question seemed to reference 'this', so I was just brining that up.  Of course it's also true you can access the variables.  That's why I just commented rather than answered, just throwing that little piece in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions here. I'll attempt to answer them:

1. You should be able to close over `account` inside the Promise callback without any issues. If you're not seeing it when you hit a breakpoint, it's simply because it's not actually used in your code yet (the debugger won't close over it dynamically, you have to have code that uses it for it to be captured).
2. `this` will be bound however the Promise implementation is implemented.
3. In your case, we're not seeing enough of the code to know what `this` could be. It all depends on how `Blog.add` is actually being called. If lexical binding via `=>` is still giving you the global namespace, then there's an "issue" with your call.

Comment: "the debugger won't close over it dynamically, you have to have code that uses it for it to be captured" - thanks for explaining this

Answer (score 4):

The situation in your code doesn't have anything to do with `this`. It's a case of simple lexical scope. Inside the callback you pass to `.then()`, all the local variables in the enclosing function (the `.add()` method) are visible, including both `account` and `url`. They're *directly* visible — `this` doesn't figure into it:

```
  response.then(function(response) {
    console.log(url);
    console.log(account);
  });
```